# Google chrome doesn't refresh select options when it deselected with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have written a script which select and deselect all options of multiple select tag on my html page. But in Google Chrome when I do deselect it still is viewed as selected, only when we put focus on select box, selection will disappear.

Is there any workaround to fix it?

[Here is an example of the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/mAd97/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.prop()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead to directly set the property of the DOM element:

```
$('#select_all').click(function(){
    $('#list option').prop('selected', true);
    return false;
});

$('#deselect_all').click(function(){
    $('#list option').prop('selected', false);
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAd97/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've tested your solution and updated. Actually there is nothing wrong with your code, it just seems selected. But when accessing it from script it works fine.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/mAd97/3/)**

**EDIT**

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/mAd97/5/)** with prop instead of `attr` and `removeAttr`

Comment: But that's exactly the problem as far is I understand. Or how would you feel as user after clicking the *deselect all* button and it still seems to be selected?